# How to map between two entities before paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider the code below:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    List<ProviderViewModel> viewModel = new List<ProviderViewModel>();
    List<Provider> businessModel = db.Providers
        .OrderBy(t => t.Name);

    foreach (Provider provider in businessModel)
    {
        viewModel.Add(new ProviderViewModel(provider));
    }

    int pageSize = 9;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(viewModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

I'm using PagedList.MVC (from NuGet) and this conversion between business model and view model. I'm using the foreach to map between both entitities, but I understand this has a performance issue. How could I map between both models? I can't use AutoMapper. My alternative approach doesn't work:

```
.Select(t => new ProviderViewModel(t))
```

Comment: Do you see a performance issue?
I suspect your alternative approach would generate the same IL as the `foreach` loop

Comment: I think you have more of performance issue because reading all of Provider entities into memory and then you do paging. It should be other way arround. First do paging and load only those records from database that apply to current page.
Otherwise AutoMapper or ValueInjecter are great tools to convert to/from domain models/view models/other models. I'm using ValueInjecter and it works very well. Never used AutoMapper, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to make sure you don't pull anymore records out of the database than you need.

As you can't use your ProviderViewModel constructor in LINQ to Entities you will have to retrieve the requested page yourself before creating your view model objects:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    List<ProviderViewModel> viewModel = new List<ProviderViewModel>();
    List<Provider> businessModel = db.Providers
                                     .OrderBy(t => t.Name);

    int pageSize = 9;
    int pageNumber = (page > 0 ? page : 1);
    int totalCount = businessModel.Count();

    foreach (Provider provider in businessModel.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1))
                                               .Take(pageSize))
    {
       viewModel.Add(new ProviderViewModel(provider));
    }

    return View(new StaticPagedList(viewModel, pageNumber, pageSize, totalCount));
}
```

StaticPagedList creates a list from one page of items rather than the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ProviderViewModel` constructor is simple, you can project directly to your class. This will save you from having to iterate the whole table. For example:

```
var viewModel = from p in db.Providers
                orderby p.Name
                select new ProviderViewModel
                {
                  Prop1 = p.Prop1,
                  Prop2 = p.Prop2 + " " + p.prop3
                  etc...
                };

int pageSize = 9;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

return View(viewModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```